# Google Maps Single JSON Overlay Visibility On Checkbox

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, geojson

Without separating JSON into 5 separate files I want to control the visibility of each JSON property based on the checkbox.

I have a single JSON overlay file.

Each JSON feature has a property AREAID.

There are 5 AREAID values:

- area1
- area2
- area3
- area4
- area5

I also have 5 checkboxes:

- Area 1
- Area 2
- Area 3
- Area 4
- Area 5

When **Area 1** checkbox is checked I want all the properties that contain **AREAID: area1** to be visible, etc.

From my research I understand that property visibility can be set with ***visible: true***.

I am assuming I need some sort of **foreach** function.

My code so far

```js
function selectall(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('switch-two');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}   
   
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 52.656963,
      lng: -112.506664
    },
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  var setMap = createArea('https://api.myjson.com/bins/iqree');


  function styleFunc(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      zIndex: 0
    };
  }

  // Infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    zIndex: 2
  });
  map.addListener('click', function() {
    setMap.revertStyle();
    infoWindow.close();
  })

  function clickFunc(event) {
    this.revertStyle();
    this.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });

    var CDNAME = event.feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
    var COLOR = event.feature.getProperty('COLOR');
    var AREAID = event.feature.getProperty('AREAID');
    
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: -3
      }
    });

    infoWindow.setContent(
  "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" +
  "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b><br />" +
  "AREAID: <b>" + AREAID + "</b>"
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }


  function mouseFunc(event) {
    this.revertStyle();
    this.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
  }

  function createArea(url) {
    var area = new google.maps.Data();
    area.loadGeoJson(url);
    area.setStyle(styleFunc);
    area.addListener('click', clickFunc);
    area.addListener('mouseover', mouseFunc);
    return area;
  }

  setArea();

  function setArea() {
    infoWindow.close();
    setMap.setMap(document.getElementById('area1').checked ? map : null);

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('area1'), 'click', setArea);
 
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="switch-field">
   
<input type="checkbox" onClick="selectall(this)"/>Select All<br/>
   
    <input type="checkbox" id="area1" name="switch-two" checked/>
    <label for="area1">Area 1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="area2" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area2">Area 2</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="area3" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area3">Area 3</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="area4" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area4">Area 4</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="area5" name="switch-two" />
    <label for="area5">Area 5</label>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data layer of Google Maps JavaScript API has `forEach()` method that allows override visibility of each feature based on the state of your checkboxes. You just need create function e.g. `setAreaVisibility()` that will override styles of features and add event listeners for `change` event of each checkbox where you will call `setAreaVisibility()`.

I modified your example, removed parts of code not related to the checkboxes behavior and created `setAreaVisibility()` function that demonstrates how you can control visibility of each feature.

Have a look at this sample code. Also note that you shouldn't create new instance of `Data` layer, because map creates one data layer by default and you can access it as `map.data` object.

```js
var map;
        
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), 
    {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {
        lat: 52.656963,
        lng: -112.506664
      },
      gestureHandling: 'greedy',
      mapTypeControl: false
    }
  );

  map.data.loadGeoJson("https://api.myjson.com/bins/iqree");

  map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
     return {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      zIndex: 0
    }; 
  });

  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('switch-two');
  checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(
        checkbox,
        'change', 
        setAreaVisibility
    );
  });    
}

function setAreaVisibility() {
    if (map) {
        map.data.forEach(function(feature){
            var areaCode = feature.getProperty('AREAID');
            var areaCheckBox = document.getElementById(areaCode);
            map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {
                visible: areaCheckBox.checked
            });
        });
    }
}

function selectall(source) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('switch-two');
  checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
  });
  setAreaVisibility();      
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">

        <input type="checkbox" onClick="selectall(this)" checked/>Select All<br/>

        <input type="checkbox" id="area1" name="switch-two" checked/>
        <label for="area1">Area 1</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="area2" name="switch-two" checked/>
        <label for="area2">Area 2</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="area3" name="switch-two" checked/>
        <label for="area3">Area 3</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="area4" name="switch-two" checked/>
        <label for="area4">Area 4</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="area5" name="switch-two" checked/>
        <label for="area5">Area 5</label>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I hope this helps!